# How to use append to store values within a loop in Python

Tags: python

I'm defining a function (`results`) that contains a for loop whose result is a random number (`a`). So, if the loop runs 10 times, for example, it will generate 10 different numbers. I would like to store those numbers in a list within the loop that I could then print to see what numbers were generated.

I thought of using append, though I don't know how to do this. This is my code so far, though the print statement doesn't work (I get an error saying I didn't use append correctly).

```
import maths

def results():
    items = []
    for _ in range(1,10):
        a = maths.numbers()
        items.append(a)
    print(items)
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

Comment: `list.append` is an "in-place" operation which returns `None`, so you don't need assignment when trying to append values.

Comment: honestly , I would name this question "how to use append?",

Comment: on the side note, do not name a variable like `list` it messes up with the default name. I strong believe python should not allow these name to override

Answer (score 1):

`.append` needs to be called on the list, not on `a`. `list` also needs to be initialized outside of the loop in order to be able to `append` to it. Here's a fixed version of your method:

```
from random import random

def results():
    # First, initialize the list so that we have a place to store the random values
    items = []
    for _ in range(1,10):
        # Generate the next value
        a = random()

        # Add the new item to the end of the list
        items.append(a)

    # Return the list
    return items
```

[Here is some more documentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append) on the `append()` method that further explains how it works.

It's also worth noting that `range` generates values from the start value up to (but not including) the stop parameter. So if your intent was to generate 10 values, you should do `range(0, 10)` since `range(1, 10)` will only give you 9 values.

If you wanted to take this a step further, you could use a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to avoid needing to use `append` altogether, and provide a parameter to indicate how many random numbers you want:

```
def results(num=10):
   return [random() for _ in range(0, num)]

# produces a list of 10 random numbers (by default)
foo = results()

# produces a list of 20 random numbers
bar = results(20)
```

Comment: I tried this but using `print(items)` instead of `return items` and now I don't get the error message, but nothing is printed... do you know why?

Comment: What error message were/are you getting? Are you calling the method? You'll need to call it like this: `results()`

Comment: I think so.. I will edit my question to include what I tried

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import maths

list_with_numbers=[]

def results():
    for _ in range(1,10):
        a = maths.numbers()
        list_with_numbers.append(a)
    print(list_with_numbers)
```

It is obvious, but don´t forget to all the function itself.

Comment: *"Not 100% sure if it is necessary"* - Not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! When do you use ´global´ then?

Comment: Unless explicitly required, it's not a good practice to use `global`. I don't recommend using it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`append` is a method you have to use on the list, so basically you would do like this: `randomList.append(a)` and don't forget to initialize your liste beforehand at the beginning of your function: `randomList = []`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few minor mistakes

- there is no `maths` module
- `a` is the number, not the list. You should append on a list
- you call `print` *after* the loop ends, not on every iteration

  from random import random

  def results():
      numbers = []

  ```
  for _ in range(1,10):
      a = random()
      print(a)
      numbers.append(a)

  return numbers
  ```